# Деактивация input с введенными данными по кнопке

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, bootstrap4

На сайте создал поиск с полем `input` и `type="search"`, разметка `Bootstrap 4`

В мобильных приложениях где есть `Поиск`, когда нажимаешь в поле `Поиск` появляется клавиатура для ввода. Чтоб её закрыть - вверху окна клавиатуры есть кнопка `Готово` или `Ввод` - разная реализация, смысл один. Второй способ - это нажать кнопку `Отмена`, которая появляется справа от поля `Поиск`

Еще вариант нажать "вне" поля `Поиск`. Важное замечание, при введенных данных в `Поиск`, закрыть клавиатуру нажатием "вне" поля `Поиск` не выйдет, так как "вне" - это ссылки с вариантами ответов на запрос

Хочу подобное реализовать для сайта

```js
$(document).on('ready', function () {

  /* Изменение ширины input при фокусе */
  $('#search').on('focus', function (event) {
    
    var input = $('#search').outerWidth()
    
    if ($('#search').val() === '') {
      $('#search').after($('<button>', {
        'class': 'btn btn-primary close-btn',
        'text': 'Отмена'
      })) 
      console.log('#1 - (focus) input пустой')    
    } else {
      $('#search').after($('<button>', {
        'class': 'btn btn-primary close-btn',
        'text': 'Отмена'
      })) 
      console.log('#2 - (focus) input не пустой, введенно ->', $('#search').val())
    }

      var button = $('.close-btn').outerWidth()
      var result = input - button
      $('#search').outerWidth(result)
  })

  /* Деактивация input при нажатии вне input */
  /* Если input не пуст, ждем выбора одного из */
  /* ответов "Поиска" что вызовет переход на другую */
  /* страницу или "Очистки" поля input */
  $('#search').on('blur', function (event) {
    if ($('#search').val() === '') {
      $('.close-btn').detach()
      $('#search').css('width', '100%')
      console.log('#3 - (blur) input пустой')    
    } else {
      $('.close-btn').detach()
      $('#search').css('width', '100%')
      console.log('#4 - (blur) input не пустой, введенно ->', $('#search').val())
    }
  }) 
    
  /* Деактивация input при нажатии на кнопку "Отмена" */
  $('.close-btn').on('click', function (event) {
      $('.close-btn').detach()
      console.log('#5 - (click) input закрыт кнопкой')
  })

})
```

```css
.btn {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

/* Не работает */
#search {
    transition: width 1s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.4s;
    -o-transition: width 0.4s;
}
/* Не работает */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JQuery JS -->        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body class="bg-dark"> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-primary">
      <div class="container">
        <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск..." aria-label="Search">
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>

</html>
```

Практически получилось. Попытка сделать проверку на пустоту поля `input` не удалась. Кнопка `Отмена` и событие `click` никак не хотят работать. Вместо этого срабатывают только события `focus` - нажатие на поле `input`, так же событие `blur` - нажатие "вне" поля `input`. Причем не зависимо пуст `input` или нет

1). Как правильно рассчитать ширину поле `input` так, чтоб в дескпотной и мобильном варианте сайта, кнопка `Отмена` появлялась только справа поля `input`?

2). Как исправить ошибку с проверкой поля `input` на пустоту, чтоб при введенных данных в поле `input` его можно было закрыть только кнопкой `Отмена` => событием `click`?

Возможно проблема из-за того, что события `focus` и `blur` работают с элементами по `id`, а событие `click` по `class`

---

Update

> https://jsfiddle.net/f69gmy4p/1/

Не понимаю как это работает `--padding` в формуле расчета ширины `input`. И почему внутренние отступы `--padding`, а не внешние `--margin`. Правда в `Bootstrap 4` нету внешних `--margin` отступов как Я увидел, только в `conteiner` родительском блоке. У `button` еще по умолчанию `display: inline-block;` он только в десктоп расширении работает, тоже не понимаю как, раз `input` постоянно `width: 100%; и display: block;`. Родительский `conteiner` имеет `display: flex;`. Вышло так у меня https://jsfiddle.net/15ey34m6/7/

Comment: у вас переменная `--margin-left` не определена

Comment: а инпуту нужно задать `transition: 1s !important;`

Comment: ну и кнопке `position absolute`

Comment: В общем  вам нужно выкинуть bootstrap или хорошенько его освоить

Comment: это если нужна анимация. Если не нужна то в вашем примере достаточно определить переменную `--margin-left: 15px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал свой велосипед по расчету ширины поля `input`, для мобильной версии

В десктопной версии для блока с классом `container`  присваивается свойство `flex-wrap: nowrap;`, что позволяет кнопке `Отмена` занять нужную ширину справа от поля `input`

В мобильной версии, блоку с классом `container` присваивается свойство `flex-wrap: wrap;` назначается оно с расширения экрана <= `768px`, что не дает кнопке `Отмена` расположиться в одну линию с полем `input`

Для решения задачи сделал проверку - меньше ли ширина блока с классом `container` чем `768px` или нет. Если да, добавлял кнопку `Отмена` и делал расчет, который менял ширину поля `input`. Если нет, просто добавлял кнопку `Отмена`

Спасибо пользователю `@h` за совет, изучить `Bootstrap` или выкинуть его вовсе =)
Я немного покопался в `Bootstrap` разметке, заметил изменение свойств нужных блоков, и немного переделал один из предложенных вариантов решений от пользователя `@h`

При анимации правда кнопка `Отмена` прыгает, видно, как поле `input` ссужается потом поднимается кнопка `Отмена`. Как исправить не знаю. В целом все работает не совсем верно https://jsfiddle.net/ukh30mgy/2/

```js
var containerSearch = document.querySelector('#container-search')
var inputSearch = document.querySelector('#input-search')
   
var containerWidth = containerSearch.offsetWidth
var inputWidth = inputSearch.getBoundingClientRect().width
   
var button = document.createElement('button')
button.className = 'btn bg-primary'
button.textContent = 'Отмена'
   
inputSearch.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    
  containerSearch.appendChild(button)
    
  if (containerWidth <= 768) {
    containerSearch.appendChild(button)
    var buttonWidth = button.getBoundingClientRect().width
    var result = Math.floor((inputWidth - buttonWidth - 15) * 100) / 100 + 'px'
    inputSearch.style.setProperty('width', result)
  }
})
   
inputSearch.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  if (inputSearch.value.trim() === '') {
    inputSearch.style.setProperty('width', '100%')
    button.remove()
  }
})
   
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  inputSearch.style.setProperty('width', '100%')     
  button.remove()
})
```

```css
#input-search, .btn {
  transition: width 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s;
  -o-transition: width 0.2s;
}

.btn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body class="bg-dark"> 
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-primary">
    <div id="container-search" class="container">
      <input type="search" id="input-search" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск">
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

---

Update

Нужно сначала изменить ширину поля `input` после показать кнопку `Отмена` - как реализовать не понимаю, ведь для расчета ширины поля `input` нужно знать ширину кнопки `Отмена` - которую можно узнать только после добавления кнопки `Отмена` в `DOM` дерево. Помогите, или совет дайте

Answer (score 1):

Еще одно решение, без каких либо расчетов ширины блока. Только определение ширины родительского блока с классом `container`

После делается проверка текущего расширения экрана, и назначается свойство родительскому блоку с классом `container` свойство `flex-wrap: nowrap;`. Кнопка `Отмена` просто прячется/открывается

```js
var containerSearch = document.querySelector('#container-search')
var containerWidth = containerSearch.offsetWidth
var inputSearch = document.querySelector('#input-search')
var closeSearch = document.querySelector('#close-search')
var closeButonSearch = closeSearch.hidden = true
     
inputSearch.addEventListener('focus', function() {

  closeSearch.hidden = false

    if (containerWidth <= 768) {
      containerSearch.style.flexWrap = 'nowrap'
      closeSearch.hidden = false
    }
})

inputSearch.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  if (inputSearch.value.trim() === '') {
    closeSearch.hidden = true
  }
})

closeSearch.addEventListener('click', function() {
  closeSearch.hidden = true
})
```

```css
.btn {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body class="bg-dark"> 
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-primary">
    <div id="container-search" class="container">
      <input type="search" id="input-search" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск">
      <button id="close-search" class="btn bg-primary">Отмена</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Один минус, анимация никак работать не хочет